# Delete Specific Post from Front-end using ajax in Django (Class Based View)

Tags: django, ajax

I have lot of posts generated using loop in django, and want to delete specific post (like Facebook delete works). I am able to get `id` of post using jquery but i am not sure what I am doing wrong to delete post. I have also implemented delete function in  `class based view`.

[Delete Post Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjyEZ.png)

existing-dashboard.html

```
{% for i in all_posts %}
... ///rest of the code
<span class="username"><a href="#">{{ i.first_name }} {{i.surname}}</a>
      <span class="more" id="more-icon">{{i.post_id}}
          <div class="more-menu" style="margin-top: 30px;">
            <span class="delete" id="{{i.post_id}}">delete</span>
          </div>
      </span>
... /// rest of the code 
</span>
{% endfor%}
```

Ajax

```
$('.delete').on('click', function(){
 var post_id = $(this).attr('id');
 alert(post_id)
 $.ajax({
   url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/existing-delete/' + post_id +'/',
   type: 'DELETE', 
   data: {},
   contentType: 'application/json',
   dataType: 'text',
   error:
   function(result){
     alert(result)
   },
   success:
   function(result){
     alert(result)
   }
 })
})
```

views.py

```
class ExistingStudentDashboard(TemplateView):
.../// rest of the code
    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        post1 = Existing_student_posts.objects.filter(id = pk).first()
        post2 = Future_student_posts.objects.filter(id = pk).first()
        post3 = Teacher_posts.objects.filter(id = pk).first()
        post4 = Employee_posts.objects.filter(id = pk).first()

        if post1:
            post1.delete()
        elif post2:
            post2.delete()
        elif post3:
            post3.delete()
        else:
            post4.delete()
        get_context_data()
```

urls.py

```
path('existing-delete/,<int:pk>', views.ExistingStudentDashboard.as_view(), name = 'existing-delete'),
```

*Getting Error in Console like bellow*

> Not Found: /existing-delete/61/

*Browser Console Error*

> [Browser Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbjsJ.png)

What I am doing wrong to delete post. Feel free to ask about more clarification. Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your path, change it to this

```
path('existing-delete/<int:pk>', views.ExistingStudentDashboard.as_view(), name = 'existing-delete'),
```

Edit:

Use this to get the csrf token in javascript

```
function getCookie(name) {
  var cookieValue = null;
  if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
       for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
         var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
         if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
           cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                            break;
      }
    }
  }
  return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
```

Then while making the ajax request, pass that on the headers.

```
headers: {"X-CSRFToken":csrftoken }
```

Comment: I am still getting `Not Found: /existing-delete/62/` in terminal.

Comment: and if you remove last slash from url?

Comment: After removing last slash I am getting this error `Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /existing-delete/62`

Comment: I am not using form to delete post, how can put `csrf` token?

Comment: so removing the last slash recognized the url, I have edited the answer for using csrf token in js

Comment: Thanks @Lag11, I added clrf token in ajax request and now is working fine. I got one more error about `TypeError: delete() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk' ` this issue was in `url`, I changed `<int:pk>` to `<int:id>`. Now it is working fine. Thanks again.